# Problem with plugin cordova-sqlite-storage

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I have a problem with a project of cordova (Ionic), the app compile sucefully. But when I add cordova-sqlite-storage plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save
```

the compile break.

```
└────╼ ionic cordova build android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
> cordova build android
9.0.0
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /home/dylan-roman/Documentos/projects/adnmovil/platforms/android/app/build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /home/dylan-roman/Documentos/projects/adnmovil/platforms/android/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/movil-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /home/dylan-roman/Documentos/projects/adnmovil/platforms/android/app/build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /home/dylan-roman/Documentos/projects/adnmovil/platforms/android/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/movil-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/dylan-roman/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/dylan-roman/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /home/dylan-roman/Android/Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.0.6113669. Versions available locally: 22.0.6917172

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
40 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 29 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: /home/dylan-roman/Documentos/projects/adnmovil/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/dylan-roman/Documentos/projects/adnmovil/platforms/android/build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information
```

If I remove the plugin compile sucefully
I allready try remove the plataform and then add android and cordova prepare

Please help me

Comment: I'm use arch linux :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some simliar problems with cordova on Mac OS while compiling for ios. I switched to cordova-plugin-sqlite-2 and it fixed the problem for me. You dont need to made any code changes, just install this plugin instead of the other sql plugin.